# Sleep seems to run first in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, sleep

I need to terminate a script if it exceeds a specific duration (10 mins)

```
examplescript.sh &
pid=$!
sleep 600 
if ['pgrep $pid']
  then 
    kill $pid
fi
```

When I tested it on my test environment, it seems working well. `examplescript.sh` runs first and if it runs for more than 10 mins, it will be terminated. However, when I tried in our production environment, it seems that sleep runs first. It waits 600s before running the `examplescript.sh`. Is there something wrong in the script?

Comment: There is a problem with the script you posted, but it has nothing to do with `sleep` running before `examplescript.sh` starts (which should be impossible). See shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 2):

There is multiply thing you should correct in your code.

`pgrep` will make a regex search on process names not pids. You can use `kill -0 pid` to check if a process with `pid` is running.

`[` (`test`) is a command[1] and should be treated as one. That means each argument should be separated by spaces. When using `[` the last argument should also be `]`:

```
[ arg1 arg2 ]
```

In your example you wont need `[` since `kill -0` will exit truly if the process is still running:

```
if kill -0 pid; then
```

And to wrap it up:

```
examplescript.sh &
pid=$!
sleep 600
if kill -0 "$pid" 2> /dev/null; then
    kill "$pid"
fi
```

`kill -0` will write an error to stderr if the process is not running anymore. So we redirect that to `/dev/null`.

[1] It's usually a build-in these days.

Another thing to note is that your script will run for 600 seconds even though `examplescript.sh` will only take a few seconds to run.

Comment: Another thing to note is that your script will run for 600 seconds even though examplescript.sh will only take a few seconds to run.    -how can I run the kill only if it exceeds for 10 mins without using sleep?

Comment: @noobLadyTea *your script* as in the script that sleeps for 600 second.

Answer (score 0):

Are your production machines significantly faster? I do not have example script to really run this on my machine, but I think your problem might be solved if you take the code you mention above

```
examplescript.sh &
pid=$!
sleep 600 
if ['pgrep $pid']
   then 
     kill $pid
fi
```

put it in a file called, say,  `monitor.sh` and run that file in the background. i.e.

```
monitor.sh &
```

Hope this helps.